# How to sort Laravel collection by distance from location?

Tags: php, sql, laravel, sorting, distance

With the following code I'm trying to do the following:

- Get all `Advertenties` from my database
- Calculate the distance of their related user to the client location
- Sort it
- return a paginated result.

Right now it does not sort by `distance` and I don't know why. It seems to me that the `orderBy` method of Laravel should sort it by `distance`.

I've tried `usort` as well but that gives me an error stating that it can't take an object.

The returned array is sorted by user_id.

```
    class AdvertentiesSearchController extends Controller
    {
    public function homeSearch(Request $request) {

    $queryWhereArr = [];
    $queryWhereArr[] = ['advertenties.title','like',"%$request->search_text%"];
    $queryWhereArr[] = ['users.name','like',"%$request->search_filter_user%"];

    if ($request->search_select != 1) {
        //doesn't include this where condition if ALL category is selected
        $queryWhereArr[] = ['subcategories.category_id','=',$request->search_select];
    }

    $user = User::find(auth()->id());
    if (!$user || !$user->latitude) {
        $user = (object) [
            "latitude" => $request->user_lat,
            "longitude" => $request->user_lng,
        ];
    }

    if ($request->search_distance > 0) {
        $queryWhereArr[] = ['users.latitude','>',$user->latitude-(1/111.1111)*$request->search_distance];
        $queryWhereArr[] = ['users.latitude','<',$user->latitude+(1/111.1111)*$request->search_distance];
        $longitudeMargin = (1/111.1111)/cos(abs($user->latitude)/57.295);
        $queryWhereArr[] = ['users.longitude','>',$user->longitude-$longitudeMargin*$request->search_distance];
        $queryWhereArr[] = ['users.longitude','<',$user->longitude+$longitudeMargin*$request->search_distance];
    }
    // return $queryWhereArr;

    $expl = explode(".",$request->search_sort_by);
    $sortBy = $expl[0].".".$expl[1];

    if ($expl[1] == "price" || $expl[1] == "created_at") {
        if ($expl[2] == "desc") {
            $advertenties = Advertentie::
                where('price', '<', 1e9)
            ->join('subcategories', 'advertenties.subcategory_id', '=', 'subcategories.id')
            ->join('users', 'advertenties.user_id', '=', 'users.id')
            ->select('advertenties.*', 'subcategories.category_id', 'users.city', 'users.latitude', 'users.longitude')
            ->where($queryWhereArr)
            ->orderByDesc($sortBy)
            ->get();
        } else {
            $advertenties = Advertentie::
                where('price', '<', 1e9)
            ->join('subcategories', 'advertenties.subcategory_id', '=', 'subcategories.id')
            ->join('users', 'advertenties.user_id', '=', 'users.id')
            ->select('advertenties.*', 'subcategories.category_id', 'users.city', 'users.latitude', 'users.longitude')
            ->where($queryWhereArr)
            ->orderBy($sortBy)
            ->get();
        }
    } else {
        $advertenties = Advertentie::
            where('price', '<', 1e9)
        ->join('subcategories', 'advertenties.subcategory_id', '=', 'subcategories.id')
        ->join('users', 'advertenties.user_id', '=', 'users.id')
        ->select('advertenties.*', 'subcategories.category_id', 'users.city', 'users.latitude', 'users.longitude')
        ->where($queryWhereArr)
        ->get();
    }

    //calculate distances and filter out far away advertenties (if necessary)
    $tempArr = [];
    $debug = [];
    if ($request->search_distance == 0) {
        foreach ($advertenties as $advertentie) {
            $advertentie->distance = null;
        }
        $tempArr = $advertenties;
    } else {
        foreach ($advertenties as $advertentie) {

            if (!$advertentie->latitude) {continue;}

            $advertentie->distance = 
             (($advertentie ->latitude  - $user->latitude)                                                                          **2)
            +((($advertentie->longitude - $user->longitude)/cos($advertentie->latitude/57.295)) **2)
            **.5 / .009;
            if ($advertentie->distance < $request->search_distance) {
                $tempArr[] = $advertentie;

            }
        }
    }

    //sort by distance
    if ($expl[1] == "distance") {
        if ($expl[2] == "desc") {
            $advertenties->sortByDesc("distance");
        } else {
            $advertenties->sortBy("distance");
        }
    }

    $offset = 6;
    $count = 0;
    $data = [];
    while ($count++ < $offset) {
        $arrPos = $count+$offset*($request->search_paginate_nr-1);
        if (isset($tempArr[$arrPos])) {
            $data[] = $tempArr[$arrPos];
        }
    }

    return $data;

}
```

// javascript on the html side

```
function searchQuery(){
    if (resultLength < 2){
        let pagNr = $('#paginate-number');
        pagNr.val(1);
    }
    jQuery.ajax({
        url: "/advertenties.search.index",
        method: 'post',
        data: {
            search_text: jQuery('#home-search-text').val(),
            search_select: jQuery('#home-search-select').val(),
            search_paginate_nr: jQuery('#paginate-number').val(),
            search_distance: jQuery('#home-search-distance').val()||0,
            user_lat: userLat||6.566,
            user_lng: userLng||53.212, 
            search_sort_by: jQuery('#select-sort-by').val(),
            search_filter_user: jQuery('#filter-user').val(),
        },
        success: function(result){
            console.log(result);
            resultLength = result.length;
            if (!resultLength) {
                let pagNr = $('#paginate-number');
                pagNr.val(1);
            }
            refreshResults(result);
        },
        error: function(jqxhr, status, exception) {
            console.log(jqxhr);
            console.log('Exception:', exception);
            console.log(status);
        }
    });
};
```

Comment: Firstly, what is `price` if checking if greated than `1e9`?

Comment: @thisiskelvin `1e9` means 10 to the power of 9. 1000000000

Comment: Did you check if your conditiion `if ($expl[1] == "distance")` is true? Otherwise it wouldn't be sorted would it? 
Btw. I can't see where `$expl` gets defined, would you mind to share it, maybe it helps?

Comment: expl is defined in the first few lines of this.
https://gyazo.com/5715991e6bcb516d204ca2e5d92ba563
$request->search_sort_by comes in formats such as like "advertenties.distance.asc" "advertenties.price.desc". This works as intended for price and created_at.

Comment: Please share the whole conditional block. It seems to be a bit complex, I bet that you don't hit the "distance" condition. With the whole block we could investigate this a bit more.

Comment: I've returned "testasdf" strings in that block to see if they return from inside the distance condition, and they do.